# Execute Update with Union

Tags: mysql, union

I have this Union statement:

```
(SELECT id FROM bby_venta_co WHERE nom_agrupacion = 'CAFE NESCAFE' 
AND promocion_id = 100000189 
AND ticket_id = 156 
AND fondo_fijo_id = 14 
AND caja_id = 1 ORDER BY costo DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id FROM bby_venta_co WHERE nom_agrupacion = 'CAFE INTERNA' 
AND promocion_id = 100000189 
AND ticket_id = 156 
AND fondo_fijo_id = 14 
AND caja_id = 1 ORDER BY costo DESC LIMIT 1);
```

which brings me two rows (214,158) and I need this information to execute my Update

```
UPDATE bby_venta_co SET tupla_usada = 1 WHERE id in(214,158);
```

But when I try to use subqueries I get a syntax error with the UNION word.

Can I mix the Update query with the Union statement? Or maybe Will I have to use two queries to get my accomplishment?. Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNION` does not work on subqueries, but on queries. Just omit the parentheses around both `SELECT`s.

And you should be able to use the whole query `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...` as a subquery that you then enclose in parentheses.

But `order by` cannot be used on the single queries of the union, but only on the unioned result. Hence the following does not work:

```
UPDATE bby_venta_co SET tupla_usada = 1 WHERE id in(
    SELECT id FROM bby_venta_co WHERE nom_agrupacion = 'CAFE NESCAFE' 
    AND promocion_id = 100000189 
    AND ticket_id = 156 
    AND fondo_fijo_id = 14 
    AND caja_id = 1 ORDER BY costo DESC LIMIT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id FROM bby_venta_co WHERE nom_agrupacion = 'CAFE INTERNA' 
    AND promocion_id = 100000189 
    AND ticket_id = 156 
    AND fondo_fijo_id = 14 
    AND caja_id = 1 ORDER BY costo DESC LIMIT 1
);
```

As you just use two single values here, two subselects with `OR` should work, avoiding the `UNION` altogether:

```
UPDATE bby_venta_co SET tupla_usada = 1 WHERE id =
    (SELECT id FROM bby_venta_co WHERE nom_agrupacion = 'CAFE NESCAFE' 
    AND promocion_id = 100000189 
    AND ticket_id = 156 
    AND fondo_fijo_id = 14 
    AND caja_id = 1 ORDER BY costo DESC LIMIT 1)
  OR id =
    (SELECT id FROM bby_venta_co WHERE nom_agrupacion = 'CAFE INTERNA' 
    AND promocion_id = 100000189 
    AND ticket_id = 156 
    AND fondo_fijo_id = 14 
    AND caja_id = 1 ORDER BY costo DESC LIMIT 1)
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It throws: Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY.

Comment: Sweet, I used one more nested select to avoid another error "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'table_name' for update in FROM clause" and now works perfectly. Thanks.